# Why does my Early 2015 MacBook Pro thinks it has a Touch ID sensor?

Tags: macbook-pro, system-settings, touch-id

Touch ID preference pane is shown on my Early 2015 MacBook Pro that doesn't have a Touch ID hardware.

Clicking on it says fingerprint limit has reached. Apple Pay says unknown error occured while adding a card.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) When did this item appeared in the preference pane? Did it happen after you installed a management profile?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I ran a bad bash script that had an infinite recursion

Comment: Is that what caused the Touch ID system pref or the Profile pref to show up? Please clarify. Maybe it will help to include the source of the script in your question. It appears that the Touch ID pref pane showed on your system due to a bug in macOS.

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong with System Preferences in general -- you're seeing several other preference panes (like Ink, Profiles, and Classroom) that are usually hidden.